# How To Create New Pandas Columns With Monthly Counts From DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, count

I have a large dataframe of crime incidents, *df*, with four columns. Here INCIDENT_DATE is datatype datetime. There are three possible types as well (Violent, Property, and non-index).

| ID | Crime | INCIDENT_DATE | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XL123445 | Aggrevated Assault | 2018-12-29 | Violent |
| XL123445 | Simple Assault | 2018-12-29 | Violent |
| XL123445 | Theft | 2018-12-30 | Property |
| TX56784 | Theft | 2018-04-28 | Property |
| ... | ... |  |  |
| CA45678 | Sexual Assault | 1991-10-23 | Violent |
| LA356890 | Burglary | 2018-12-21 | Property |

I want to create a new dataframe, where I can get the monthly counts (for each ID) of type property and violent,  and a row for the sum total of incidents for that ID during that month.

So I would want something like:

| ID | Year_Month | Violent | Property | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XL123445 | 2018-08 | 19654 | 500 | 20154 |
| TX56784 | 2011-07 | 17 | 15 | 32 |
| ... | ... | ... |  |  |
| CA45678 | 1992-06 | 100 | 100 | 200 |
| LA356890 | 1993-05 | Property | 50 | 50 |

I have created a previous dataframe with column 'Year_Month' before that only took into account aggregated counts of crime incidents for each ID, but this ignored 'Type'. I did this with:

```
df1 = (df.value_counts(['ID', df['INCIDENT_DATE'].dt.to_period('M').rename('Year_Month')])
     .rename('Count').reset_index())
```

Is there a way I can carry over this same logic while creating two additional columns, as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you were very close:

```py
df1 = df.value_counts([
    'ID', df['INCIDENT_DATE'].dt.to_period('M').rename('Year_Month'), 'Type',
]).unstack('Type', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df1 = df1.assign(Total=df1.sum(axis=1)).reset_index()
```

On your sample data:

```py
>>> df1
         ID Year_Month  Property  Violent  Total
0   CA45678    1991-10         0        1      1
1  LA356890    2018-12         1        0      1
2   TX56784    2018-04         1        0      1
3  XL123445    2018-12         1        2      3
```